# Determine whether code being run is in DRAM or SRAM

Tags: python, caching, operating-system

Is there any way to determine where my code is being run? I see a lot of utility in being able to optimize my code for running in my cache, but I'm not sure how possible it is to dig down to that level. Any ideas on how possible this is? Would love to do this with Python, but if possible in some other language that would be acceptable.

Comment: You're not Mel. No one is Mel.

Comment: Wait, I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: If you have a reason to dig that deep (and you don't), Python is not the language you should be using.

Comment: [The Story of Mel](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/story-of-mel.html).

Comment: Caches are orders of magnitude faster regardless of which language you're using. This is also more for general coding practice edification.

Comment: You might be able to devise a timing test that would tell you which type of memory your code is being executed from. If you meant non-volatile SRAM, then you may be able to detect whether writing to memory with in it actually changes its content.

Answer (score 0):

General rule of thumb: The code that is currently executing is in cache. If it wasn't, it is now. The code that was executing a little while ago is probably in cache too. There is no way to tell what's in cache, especially since looking at something caches it; the only language you might have a chance in is assembly. If you want to optimize for caching, optimize for [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference); read things that are near each other in memory together, and use them as much as possible before moving on to more data. However, you *should not* be worrying about this in Python.

Comment: To be fair, you should worry about locality all the time as it makes a very serious difference. You could also in theory mock up a copy of your cpu and run the thing in parallel which would tell you if something is in cache or dram, but I imagine there's a way to do this without building a copy of your computer.

Comment: Python is going to wreck your locality of reference. Reference counts require writing to an object whenever you create or delete a reference to it. There is no JIT, so all code goes through the interpreter. Methods must be looked up on every invocation, generally requiring several dict lookups. There is no way to specify that you want certain objects to be allocated next to each other, even for things like ints. If you are trying so hard to optimize that you want to *programmatically determine what code is in cache*, ditching Python should be your first move.